# How to map to nested object with private field using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I want to do mapping *CreateMap<MoneyRangeSource, MoneyRangeDest>()*

How to perform it using **AutoMapper**?

```
 public class MoneyRangeSource
 {
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
 }

 public class MoneyRangeDest
 {        
    public Money Start { get; set; }
    public Money End { get; set; }
 }

 public class Money
 {
   private string value;

   public Money(string money)
   {            
      value = money;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a [custom type converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) for the `string` to `Money` conversion.
This allows to pass an argument to the `constructor` of the `Money` class

```
CreateMap<string, Money>().ConvertUsing(src => new Money(src));
```

and a regular mapping from `MoneyRangeSource` to `MoneyRangeDest`

```
CreateMap<MoneyRangeSource, MoneyRangeDest>()
```